# What are sensible dichotomies of "abstract"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice

Which of the following dichotomies sound "natural" to the native English speaker?

- abstract vs. real
- abstract vs. real-life
- abstract vs. real-world
- abstract vs. concrete
- abstract vs. physical
- abstract vs. specific

I am especially interested in finding dichotomous namings for "abstract structures/systems" as represented e.g. by mathematical structures like graphs in the sense of networks. What sounds most "natural" and most appropriate:

- real structures/systems
- real-life structures/systems
- real-world structures/systems
- concrete structures/systems
- physical structures/systems (which is too narrow)
- specific structures/systems

Further suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Why dichotomous? Most structures aren't limited to binary distinctions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say abstract vs. physical, and abstract vs. concrete sound the most "natural" to me. Closely followed by abstract vs. specific, and then abstract vs. real-world.

Would theoretical physics vs experimental physics be the kind of dichotomy you're looking for?